# Dynamic creation of tabs in Rmarkdown does not work for ggplot while it does for plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr, ggplotly

I've been willing to dynamically create `tab` contents in `rmarkdown`.

I've created an `in_tabs` that seems to work for everything but `ggplot` plots.

The way it works is that it creates the `Rmd` code necessary to display nested lists in tabs.

The following reproducible example shows the issue:

````
---                                                                                                                                    
title: "test"                                                                                                                          
output: html_document                                                                                                                  
---                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                       
```{r setup, include = FALSE}                                                                                                          
library(ggplot2)                                                                                                                       
library(plotly)                                                                                                                        
l1 <- list(p1 = data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10))                                                                                            
l2 <- list(p2 = data.frame(x=100:110, y=100:110))                                                                                      
gplot <- function(data) {                                                                                                              
    p <- ggplot(data) + aes(x=x, y=y) + geom_point() + geom_line()                                                                     
    return(p)                                                                                                                          
}                                                                                                                                      
gplotly <- function(data) {                                                                                                            
    p <- ggplot(data) + aes(x=x, y=y) + geom_point() + geom_line()                                                                     
    return(ggplotly(p))                                                                                                                
}                                                                                                                                      
```                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                       
```{r, code, include = FALSE}                                                                                                          
in_tabs <- function(l, labels = names(l), level, knit = TRUE, close_tabset = FALSE) {                                                  
    if(is.null(labels)) {                                                                                                              
        stop("labels are NULL, it is required not to be so that the tabs have proper names")                                           
    }                                                                                                                                  
    names(l) <- labels                                                                                                                 
    rmd_code <- lapply(seq_along(l), FUN = function(i) obj_to_rmd(l[[i]], name = names(l)[i], level = level + 1L))                     
    if(isTRUE(getOption("knitr.in.progress"))) {                                                                                       
        res <- knitr::knit(text = unlist(rmd_code), quiet = TRUE)                                                                      
        cat(res)                                                                                                                       
    } else {                                                                                                                           
        if(!knit) {                                                                                                                    
            cat(unlist(rmd_code))                                                                                                      
        } else {                                                                                                                       
            return(l)                                                                                                                  
        }                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                  
    if(close_tabset) {                                                                                                                 
        cat(paste(get_section(level), "{.unlisted .unnumbered .toc-ignore .tabset}", "\n"))                                            
    }                                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                       
get_section <- function(level) {                                                                                                       
    paste(rep("#", times = level), collapse = "")                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                       
get_tabset <- function(obj) {                                                                                                          
    ifelse(inherits(obj, "list"), "{.tabset}", "")                                                                                     
}                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                       
obj_to_rmd <- function(obj, parent_name = "l", name, level) {                                                                          
    section_code <- sprintf("%s %s %s\n", get_section(level), name, get_tabset(obj))                                                   
    if(!inherits(obj, "list")) {                                                                                                       
            rmd_code <- c("```{r, echo = FALSE}\n",                                                                                    
                          sprintf("%s$`%s`\n", parent_name, name),                                                                     
                          "```\n",                                                                                                     
                          "\n")                                                                                                        
    } else {                                                                                                                           
        rmd_code <- c("\n",                                                                                                            
                      lapply(X = seq_along(obj),                                                                                       
                             FUN = function(i) obj_to_rmd(obj[[i]], sprintf("%s$`%s`", parent_name, name), names(obj)[i], level + 1L)))
    }                                                                                                                                  
    return(c(section_code, rmd_code))                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                      
```                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                       
# plot 1 {.tabset}                                                                                                                     
```{r, plot-01, results = "asis"}                                                                                                      
in_tabs(lapply(l1, FUN = gplot), labels = names(l1), level = 1L)                                                                       
```                                                                                                                                    
                                                                  
# plot 2 {.tabset}                                                
```{r, plot-02, results = "asis"}                                 
in_tabs(lapply(l2, FUN = gplot), labels = names(l2), level = 1L)  
```                                                               
                                                                  
# plot 3 {.tabset}                                                
```{r, plot-03, results = "asis"}                                 
in_tabs(lapply(l1, FUN = gplotly), labels = names(l1), level = 1L)
```                                                               
                                                                  
# plot 4 {.tabset}                                                
```{r, plot-04, results = "asis"}                                 
in_tabs(lapply(l2, FUN = gplotly), labels = names(l2), level = 1L)
```
````

The output I get is:

**You can see the issue that the first plot is actually identical the the second plot while it should not !!!**

[image]

When using `plotly` (or anything else I have tested) it works as expected as shown on plots 3 and 4

[image]

Could you help me fix it, I am happy with testing for the class of the object `obj_to_rmd` receives.

PS: `rmd` code `in_tabs` generates can be seen by running `in_tabs(..., knit = FALSE)`. For instance

````
in_tabs(lapply(l1, FUN = gplot), labels = names(l1), level = 1L, knit = FALSE)
## p1 
 ```{r, echo = FALSE}
 plot(l$`p1`)
 ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about all the details so you have to keep in mind that may answer involves some guessing.

When knitting the document `knitr` runs the `ggplot2` code and saves the resulting plot as a `png` where the filename is the name of the chunk.

As far as I got it from inspecting the `md` file generated by `knitr` (by adding `keep_md: true` to the YAML) the issue with your code is, that "all" plots are saved under the same filename `unnamed-chunk-1-1.png`, i.e. both of your ggplot chunks look like this in the final `md`:

```
![](bar1_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-1-1.png)<!-- -->
```

This could also be seen by having a look the the `figure-html` folder which includes only one `png`.

Put differently your code basically works fine, but you are permanently overwriting the `png`s so you end up with a document where only the last saved plot shows up. That's also the reason why your code works for `ggplotly` as in that case the HTML/JS code necessary to render the chart is directly added to the `md` file.

Under normal circumstances `knitr` ensures that all plots are saved under unique filenames. I can only guess why this fails in your case. My guess is that the issue is that you knit each chunk separately when calling `knitr::knit(text = unlist(rmd_code), quiet = TRUE)`, i.e. each unnamed chunk gets the same name and each is ggplot is accordingly saved under the same filename.

Having said that, to achieve your desired result you could add a unique name to each of the dynamic code chunks so that each plot is saved under a unique filename.

As a quick solution I added an `id` argument to your `in_tabs` and `obj_to_rmd` functions. In case of `in_tabs` the `id` is simple the identifier of the chunk in your main document, while in case of `obj_to_rmd` I additionally add an identifier for the list element via `id = paste(id, i, sep = "-")`:

````
---                                                                                                                             
title: "test"
output:
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}                                                                                                     
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
d1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
d2 <- data.frame(x = 100:110, y = 100:110)
l1 <- list(p1 = d1)
l2 <- list(p1 = d2, p2 = d1)
gplot <- function(data) {
  ggplot(data) +
    aes(x = x, y = y) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line()
}
```
                                                                                                                                       
```{r, code, include = FALSE}                                                                                                     
in_tabs <- function(l, labels = names(l), level, knit = TRUE, close_tabset = FALSE, id) {
  if (is.null(labels)) {
    stop("labels are NULL, it is required not to be so that the tabs have proper names")
  }
  names(l) <- labels

  rmd_code <- lapply(seq_along(l), FUN = function(i) obj_to_rmd(l[[i]], name = names(l)[i], level = level + 1L, id = paste(id, i, sep = "-")))
  
  if (isTRUE(getOption("knitr.in.progress"))) {
    res <- knitr::knit(text = unlist(rmd_code), quiet = TRUE)
    cat(res)
  } else {
    if (!knit) {
      cat(unlist(rmd_code))
    } else {
      return(l)
    }
  }
  if (close_tabset) {
    cat(paste(get_section(level), "{.unlisted .unnumbered .toc-ignore .tabset}", "\n"))
  }
}

get_section <- function(level) {
  paste(rep("#", times = level), collapse = "")
}

get_tabset <- function(obj) {
  if (inherits(obj, "list")) "{.tabset}" else ""
}

obj_to_rmd <- function(obj, parent_name = "l", name, level, id) {
  section_code <- sprintf("%s %s %s\n", get_section(level), name, get_tabset(obj))
  if (!inherits(obj, "list")) {
    rmd_code <- c(
      sprintf("```{r plot-%s, echo = FALSE}\n", id),
      sprintf("%s$`%s`\n", parent_name, name),
      "```\n",
      "\n"
    )
  } else {
    rmd_code <- c(
      "\n",
      lapply(
        X = seq_along(obj),
        FUN = function(i) obj_to_rmd(obj[[i]], sprintf("%s$`%s`", parent_name, name), names(obj)[i], level + 1L)
      )
    )
  }
  return(c(section_code, rmd_code))
}
```                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                  
# plot 1 {.tabset}                                                                                                                     
```{r, plot-01, results = "asis"}
p1 <- lapply(l1, FUN = gplot)
in_tabs(p1, labels = names(l1), level = 1L, id = 1)
```
                                                                  
# plot 2 {.tabset}                                                
```{r, plot-02, results = "asis"}    
p2 <- lapply(l2, FUN = gplot)
in_tabs(p2, labels = names(l2), level = 1L, id = 2)
```
````

[image]

Comment: That was it thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

As stefan mentioned, the issue is with the ggplot's id, since they somehow have the same code chunk, even though you named the chunks differently.I don't know the reason for this behaviour, but you can bypass it by setting

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
options(knitr.duplicate.label = "allow")
```
````

at the beginning of your document. That should do the trick. It will give different chunk names to each of your plots. You can verify that by removing `results = "asis"`from your ggplots to see that they no longer have the same id.

[image]

```
## ## p1 
## 
## <img src="test_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-2-1.png" width="672" />


## ## p2 
## 
## <img src="test_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-1-2-1.png" width="672" />
```

You can read more about allowing duplicated chunks at [bookdown.org](https://rmd4sci.njtierney.com/common-problems-with-rmarkdown-and-some-solutions.html#duplication-duplicated-chunk-names)

Comment: That was it thank you very much, I added a random string on the "created" chunks